# Implemented Managed Identity for App Service to access Application Insights .NET Core 3.1

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-core, azure-managed-identity

I implemented my webapp so that it is able to log data to Application Insights through managed identity.
I noticed now that after my implementation I am getting an error on the home page of the webapp:

[image]

This is the page that comes up on my app when loads up when a valid route is not found. If I was to go to the Console this is what I see:
[image]

Like I mentioned, this came after Managed Identity was implemented.

Comment: Can you please share your code repo?

Comment: .NET Core 3.1 reached End Of Life in December 2022. The oldest supported .NET Core version is .NET 6. End Of Life means no Azure service is obliged to support it, especially 1 year after EOL.

Comment: How did you add Identity, given that 3.1 is unsupported? The current guides and packages target the currently supported version. The classes, modules and references they use may not exist in older versions

Comment: How you have configured ApplicationInsights?

Comment: So you have MS Entra Auth only on app insights ?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Panagiotis Kanavos for the comments.

- Yes, .NET Core 3.1 is OutofSupport and your App may not work as expected.
- If you still want to continue with the old Core 3.1 version, check the below steps.

Thanks @Stefano Demiliani for the clear explanation.

I have taken references from [MSDoc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/azure-ad-authentication?WT.mc_id=Portal-AppInsightsExtension&tabs=net) and [demiliani](https://demiliani.com/2021/08/30/azure-ad-authentication-for-application-insights-how-to-use-it-and-the-impact-on-business-central-telemetry/#:%7E:text=To%20enable%20the%20managed%20identity%20to%20access%20the,%28in%20my%20case%20it%E2%80%99s%20my%20Azure%20Function%20app%29%3A)

- To work with Managed Identity, you need to assign a new role `Monitoring Metrics Publisher` in Application Insights.

[image]

- Even the Properties section in Application Insights says the same.
  [image]
- Disable the Local Authentication.

***My `.csproj` file:***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">
  <PropertyGroup>    
  <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>    
  <ApplicationInsightsResourceId>/subscriptions/**********/resourceGroups/********/providers/microsoft.insights/components/Core3AppInsights</ApplicationInsightsResourceId>   
    <UserSecretsId>********</UserSecretsId>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.10.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.21.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource" Version="8.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

In Startup.cs file, add under ConfigureServices,`services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();`.

[image]